# hapi.js nested plugins and folder structure

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am new to [hapi](http://hapijs.com/) and for the last few days I've been trying out different project structures in order to keep the concerns separated and the codebase somewhat maintainable while not deviating too much from the "hapi" way of doing things. You can take a look at the folder structure [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jirz.png).

My project consists of a simple RESTful API, so I don't need to worry about views, rendering and so on. What I've ended up doing, and I'm not sure (yet) if this is **idiotic** or not, is to have the whole API logic (route handling, authorization, db access, etc) registered as a plugin. What this allows me to do is:

- easily prefix all the routes with "/api/vX/" for a particular API version
- easily swap API versions by registering all the dependencies (basically other plugins) for a particular API version in the plugin itself; this is what I meant in the title by "nested plugins"

I was hoping I could get some insight from other people using hapi and maybe see what what they are using, what's working for them and what's not.

Also, is nesting plugins "hapi"? I've taken a peak at the repos for a few of the popular hapi plugins that are out there and I haven't seen people doing it.  Thanks!